# Linked lists in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a Linked Lists assignment for school although I am just getting the hang of class constructors.  I am trying to simply get the basics of the linked list data structure down, and I understand the basic concept.  I have watched lots of Youtube tutorials and the like, but where I am failing to understand is how to print out the cargo or data in my nodes using a loop.

I have written something along these lines:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value, pointer):
        self.value = value
        self.pointer = pointer

node4 = Node(31, None)

node3 = Node(37, None)

node2 = Node(62, None)

node1 = Node(23, None)
```

Now...I understand that each node declaration is a call to the class constructor of Node and that the list is linked because each node contains a pointer to the next node, but I simply don't understand how to print them out using a loop.  I've seen examples using global variables for the "head" and I've seen subclasses created to accomplish the task.  I'm old and dumb.  I was wondering if someone could take it slow and explain it to me like I'm 5.  If anyone out there has the compassion and willingness to hold my hand through the explanation, I would be greatly obliged.  Thank you in advance, kind sirs.

Comment: You don't have any linked list in your above snippet - only nodes.  You now need a proper `LinkedList` class with a reference to it's first ("head" or however you want to name it) node and methods to add or remove values, get value at a given position, etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your nodes should be created something like this :

```
node4 = Node(31, node3)
node3 = Node(37, node2)
node2 = Node(62, node1)
node1 = Node(23, None)
```

Now, i am sure you can see that the last node in the list would point to None. So, therefore, you can loop through the list until you encounter None. Something like this should work :

```
printhead = node4
while True:
    print(printhead.value)
    if printhead.pointer is None:
        break;
    else :
        printhead = printhead.pointer
```

Comment: `NameError` in the first, second and third line

Comment: Mac...thank you so much.  I knew it was not so difficult to grasp.  I made a mistake when I wrote my original post, too.  I meant to type: node4 = Node(31, None)  node3 = Node(37, node4)   node2 = Node(62, node3)   node1 = Node(23, node2)     .....................sorry about that....I made the post when I was very tired...(that's my excuse, anyway)...thank you so much though...that was a very simple example...exactly what I needed...too often I think that people take cries for help as opportunities to show off how badly they can confuse us noobs instead of actually helping us

Comment: Glad to help. All good, its an easy mistake to make. Although, I would say that @ElmoVanKielmo 's answer is technically more correct. I however, was trying to get the point across, even though there are issues with my answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic linked list implementation for educational purposes only.

```
from __future__ import print_function
"""The above is needed for Python 2.x unless you change 
`print(node.value)` into `print node.value`"""

class Node(object):
    """This class represents list item (node)"""

    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        """Store item value and pointer to the next node"""
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node


class LinkedList(object):
    """This class represents linked list"""

    def __init__(self, *values):
        """Create nodes and store reference to the first node"""
        node = None
        # Create nodes in reversed order as each node needs to store reference to next node
        for value in reversed(values):
            node = Node(value, node)
        self.first_node = node
        # Initialize current_node for iterator
        self.current_node = self.first_node

    def __iter__(self):
        """Tell Python that this class is iterable"""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Return next node from the linked list"""
        # If previous call marked iteration as done, let's really finish it
        if isinstance(self.current_node, StopIteration):
            stop_iteration = self.current_node
            # Reset current_node back to reference first_node
            self.current_node = self.first_node
            # Raise StopIteration to exit for loop
            raise stop_iteration
        # Take the current_node into local variable
        node = self.current_node
        # If next_node is None, then the current_node is the last one, let's mark this with StopIteration instance
        if node.next_node is None:
            self.current_node = StopIteration()
        else:
            # Put next_node reference into current_node
            self.current_node = self.current_node.next_node
        return node

linked_list = LinkedList(31, 37, 62, 23)

for node in linked_list:
    print(node.value)
```

This doesn't handle many cases properly (including **break** statement in the loop body) but the goal is to show minimum requirements for linked list implementation in Python.